# Dynamic background colour for code blocks

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting, programming

Years ago I saw a feature in XCode where nested code blocks (delimited by {}) containing my cursor had graded background shades, with the lightest at my cursor, and the darkest at the outer level.

.e.g.

```
//Very Dark Grey bg
if(true){ // Dark Grey bg
    Velociraptor:
    for(i=0;i<foo;i++){ // Grey bg
        bar();
        while(true){// Light Grey bg
            do{// White bg
                // cursor here (ominous, isn't it)
                goto Velociraptor;
            }while()
        }
    }
}
```

And it would dynamically change to

```
// Dark Grey bg
if(true){ // Grey bg
    Velociraptor:
    for(i=0;i<foo;i++){ // Light Grey bg
        bar();
        // cursor here
        while(true){// White bg
            do{// White bg
                goto Velociraptor;
            }while()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a package for this in Emacs / can it be done?